# SSIS Package validation errors due to expected empty variable

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-2014, ssis-2012

I have a number of SSIS packages which I have deployed to SQL Server 2014. The packages take a file parameter which I place into a variable. From that rawFile variable a number of variables are derived. The packages are running fine in my development environment and are providing me with the output I am expecting. The problem I have is that I am unable to deploy the .dtsx packages using SSMS because of the following (I think expected because there is no filename yet) errors:

Error loading XXXXXXX.dtsx: Casting expression "SUBSTRING(@[User::varRawFile],19,2)" from data type "DT_WSTR" to data type "DT_I4" failed with error code 0xC00470C2.

Error loading XXXXXXX.dtsx: Error code 0x80020005 occurred attempting to convert from data type DT_WSTR to data type DT_I4.

Error saving XXXXXXX.dtsx: The expression for variable "varDataMonth" failed evaluation. There was an error in the expression.

In design mode I have DelayValidation and ValidateExternalMetadata set True and False for all objects respectively. I am able to work around the issue by deploying directly from Visual Studio but this isn't inline with my organisation's change management process.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Any chance you can alter your logic internally in your package to store the month as a string, not an INT? Are you doing numeric calculations on the month? If you aren't doing numeric calculations on the month then change the data type to a string and all of those casting errors will go away. Can you also tag the verision of SSIS ? 2012 is very different to 2008.

Comment: Unfortunately for one of them I am. The file I am processing comes in with this month's date but the data, while it doesnt contain a field for it, is for the previous month. I am deriving a column for the month and subtracting 1: `(DT_I4)SUBSTRING(@[User::varRawFile],19, 2 )-1`. I have updated the tags with versions numbers too.

Comment: Have you tried moving your expressions into an expression task? I guess right now its 'inline' in property pages etc. I think this means the expression isn't evaluated until runtime. If you try it and it works we both learn something.

Comment: check if you have `delay validation` set to `true` on the connection object itself.